# What is the result of casting a pointer to a string literal as an int pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to c programming language and learning pointers now. i need a little clarification in pointer casting.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

char *c = "hello";
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
    printf("c:%c %d\n",c[i],c[i]);
int *ip = (int*)c;
printf("after casting");
printf("c:%d\n",*ip);
return 0;
}
OUTPUT:
c:h 104
c:e 101
c:l 108
c:l 108
c:o 111
after castingc:1819043176
```

So, what is this value 1819043176? any garbage value or it represents anything. 
In this program, after casting the char pointer to integer pointer. this printf("c:%d\n",*ip); statement shows some value
of ip like 1819043176. i can't understand what is this value 1819043176

please help me to understand. thank you.

Comment: You're breaking the strict aliasing rule, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: I suggest you print the casted value as *hex* and keep an [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) nearby (or just print the separate characters as hex as well).

Comment: Your not really allowed to do that cast. But if you convert 1819043176 to hex you get `0x6C6C6568`. Surprisingly that is the ASCII codes for `'l'`, `'l'`, `'e'`, and `'h'`. Guess where those values came from.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, `char*` is allowed to alias any other pointer type. Not the other way around as is happening here though, `char*` to `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program does something that is not allowed - converting a `char` pointer to an `int` pointer. Depending on a platform, some `char` pointers may have no valid representation as an `int` pointer, so the conversion is prohibited; what you see is undefined behavior.

However, there is a rational explanation of what is going on. Consider this program that copies a string into an array of integers:

```
int data[2] = {0};
strcpy((char*)data, "hello");
printf("%s\n", (char*)data);
printf("%d\n", data[0]);
```

This is allowed, because `int` pointer can be converted to `char` pointer on all platforms (in fact, standard requires all object pointers to be convertible to `char*`).

The result [printed](https://ideone.com/GIw3p7) in this program above matches the value that you get, i.e. 1819043176. This is a platform-specific number resulting from re-interpreting the initial four bytes of `"hello"` as an integer.